# Updating an entry from a table ONLY if the username is same as the user that created the entry PDO

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

Too give some context.  I am creating a page where users can leave reviews.  I want to be able to alter the table so that if a user wanted to change /update the review that they created they can using an identical form- providing that the username is the same as the username left by the review. I then want all old data from the review to be overwritten.

Here is the query to that i used to insert the details:

```
$sql = "UPDATE reviews SET book_id = :book_id, user = :user, 
review = :review, rating = :rating WHERE user = '.$username'";     
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);


    $query->execute(array(

    ':book_id' => $book,
    ':user' => $username,
    ':review' => $review,
     ':rating' => $rating   
         ));
    echo "You updated your review!  ";

    }else{
    echo "error occured: ".$error;
    exit();
}
```

The output: I managed to update every entry with the input that i entered, so now all entries are the same. This isn't what I want, I want to update an entry on a specific book - again if the username matches (same person as created the review). Can anyone show me how to get the desire output? thanks in advance.

Edit: I added a where clause, but it enters nothing in the database and no errors.

Comment: then use your primary key to update that specific row

Comment: Why not simply use a WHERE clause to add a constraint on the book_id and username? I would also recommend that you read up on some SQL basics or work through a tutorial (googling turned up [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) which looks quite nice at first glance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend looking up simple SQL tutorials to learn more, but what you want is a condition that checks both the user and the book_id fields. You can do this by specifying both conditions like this:

```
... WHERE [condition1] AND [condition2] ...
```

For example:

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE column3 = :value1 AND column4 = :value;
```

I seriously recommend you look up the basic concepts though, it'll probably save you a lot of time later on.